# Remove false values in object

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, arraylist

The problem that I'm facing is -removing the values in the onject that has the property `false`
Here is the object

```
var myObj={105:true,183:false,108:true,106:false}
```

I'm able to get the values in an array by using the following logic:

`Object.keys(myObj)` gives `["105","183","108","106"]`
But I need a way to remove the values that have the property false and generate as `["105",108"]`.Can you help me out ?

Comment: Iterate properties and remove them

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've just created a solution to your problem on JSBin: [Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/jodizo/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

Please find below the code:

```
var myObj={105:true,183:false,108:true,106:false};
var myArray = [];

function RemoveFalseAndTransformToArray () {
  for (var key in myObj) {
    if(myObj[key] === false) {
        delete myObj[key];
    } else {
        myArray.push(key);
    }
  }
}
RemoveFalseAndTransformToArray();
console.log("myObj: ", myObj);
console.log("myArray: ", myArray);
// result = ["105", "108"]
```

Please, let me know if you have any question.

Answer (score 13):

You have the keys of the object in an array. Run filter over it.

```
var myObj={105:true,183:false,108:true,106:false};

var result = Object.keys(myObj).filter(function(x) { 
    return myObj[x] !== false; 
});
// result = ["105", "108"]
```

Comment: Note: this answer requires IE9+

Answer (score 3):

To remove those properties you can use this algorithm:

```
for (k in myObj)
{
  if (myObj.hasOwnProperty(k) && myObj[k] === false)
  {
      delete myObj[k];
  }
}
```

If you are just interested in the keys of non-`false` values, you can use:

```
var keys = Object.keys(myObj).filter(function (k) {
  return myObj[k] !== false;
});
```

The `hasOwnProperty()` check is necessary because objects may contain non-user properties (such as `prototype`) which you really don't want to mess with.

Answer (score 2):

You need to iterate over the object using `for...in` loop

```
var myObj={105:true,183:false,108:true,106:false}
for(var key in myObj){
  if(myObj.hasOwnProperty(key) && myObj[key] == false){
   delete myObj[key];
  }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(myObj)) //{"105":true,"108":true}
console.log(Object.keys(myObj)) //["105", "108"]
```

Answer (score 2):

ES6 has a one line way to do this, **this mutates the original array!**

```
   Object.keys(myObj).map(key => !myObj[key] && delete myObj[key])
```

to avoid this use the spread operator

```
   const filteredObj = [...myObj]
   Object.keys(filteredObj).map(key => !filteredObj[key] && delete filteredObj[key])
```

Answer (score 1):

One liner, no mutation

```
Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries({105:true,183:false,108:true,106:false})
 .filter(([,v]) => v)
)
```